# I work with Humble ROS and I want to use ros_control

Tags: ros-humble, differential-drive, ros2-control, diff-drive-controller

I installed all packages I need and write my `controll.xacro` file and `my_controller.yaml` file and write launch file correctly and in my source file I clone serial package.

However,  when I clone `diffdrive_arduino` package but with foxy branch so I cannot `colcon build` it.

If i `colcon build`

```
In file included from /home/omar/project_ws/src/ros2_control_diff_drive/diffdrive/src/diffdrive_arduino.cpp:1:
/home/omar/project_ws/src/ros2_control_diff_drive/diffdrive/include/diffdrive_arduino/diffdrive_arduino.h:7:10: fatal error: hardware_interface/base_interface.hpp: No such file or directory
    7 | #include "hardware_interface/base_interface.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/diffdrive_arduino.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/diffdrive_arduino.dir/src/diffdrive_arduino.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:113: CMakeFiles/diffdrive_arduino.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

This error appears.

If I do not build it, I launch my launch file the next error will appear

```
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-2]: process has died [pid 10267, exit code -2, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_o5gavlx1 --params-file /home/omar/project_ws/install/diff_bot/share/diff_bot/config/diff_drive_controller.yaml'].
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 10255]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome at RSE. It is not possible to know what could be the problem if you don't add your code (package.xml, CMakeLists.txt, etc). Could you provide a public repository?

I'd suggest that you start with the [official demos](https://control.ros.org/humble/doc/ros2_control_demos/doc/index.html) to learn how to setup ros2_control.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing a Package try this:

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-hardware-interface
```